# Using the .split() method in python

Tags: python, string, methods, split, newline

I'm taking an input from a text file and trying to split the text whenever it comes across the "\n" character, but it doesn't split anything. I tried it on tabs and spaces and it works perfectly. For some reason it doesn't work with the newline character. Does it have something to do with the way I'm getting the string? I'm piping the file into the program. When I give the same lines of code a try on IDLE it works fine.

```
t= input("input string : " )
...


tps = t.split('\n')
print(tps)
```

Comment: Was the file created on a Windows machine? If so the line endings are likely `\r\n`

Answer (score 3):

`input()` only reads one line.  You need to run it in a loop, reading a line at a time:

```
try:
    while True:
        t = input("input string : " )  # Or raw_input for Python 2
        print t.replace('e', 'X')
except EOFError:
    pass
```

Run that example as `python x.py < x.py` and it prints:

```
input string : try:
input string :     whilX TruX:
input string :         t = raw_input("input string : " )
input string :         print t.rXplacX('X', 'X')
input string : XxcXpt EOFError:
input string :     pass
input string :
```

Comment: really this is the answer?!!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @MartijnPieters actually my question is to OP

Comment: I have it in a loop in my program, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @HarryHarry: My first version would finish as soon as it hit a blank line, which could have been the problem.  Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

For splitting a multi-line string on newlines, you would normally use [`str.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) instead, which handles different newline conventions:

```
>>> 'Test\r\nlines\nall mixed\r'.splitlines()
['Test', 'lines', 'all mixed']
```

Note that `input()` only gives you the *first line* in any case; for multi-line input you probably want to read from `sys.stdin` instead:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    # handle a line
```

or read lines in a loop:

```
while True:
    line = input()
```

Comment: Splitting on `\n` would still split, but the OP says "it doesn't split anything."

Comment: @RichieHindle: It would not split if `\r` is used. Not likely, I'll grant you, but still.

Comment: You'd need a time machine (or a working MacOS <= 9 box, whichever is harder to come by).  :-)